# How to perfectly run socket programming in android service?

Tags: java, android

Actually, I can run socket programming in single thread in android. But I can't make that in android service. I want that in service which runs continuously for response. Also, I want that **pass string from service to activity**. How can I do that?.

Here is the code of activity which sends data and starts service.

**ServerActivity.JAVA:**

```
package com.ctpl.baatein;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.ctpl.baatein.service.ServerResponseService;

public class ServerActivity extends Activity {

    Context context;
    ImageView image;
    EditText textOut;
    TextView textIn;
    public String res = "";
    String objStr = "";
    ResponseReceiver resReceiver;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_server); 
        textOut = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textout);
        Button buttonSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
        textIn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textin);
        image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(buttonSendOnClickListener);
    }

         Button.OnClickListener buttonSendOnClickListener
         = new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            try {
                obj.put("cell_id","562");
                obj.put("device_id","E5");
                obj.put("device_model","sms");
                obj.put("lat","");
                obj.put("lng","");
                obj.put("wifi_id","7");
                obj.put("op","block");
                obj.put("userPhone","");
                obj.put("blockedPhone","");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Socket start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            objStr = obj.toString();
            Intent sIntent = new Intent(context, ServerResponseService.class);
            sIntent.putExtra("REQ_STRING", objStr);
            context.startService(sIntent);

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    textIn.setText(res);
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {

        //Register BroadcastReceiver
          //to receive event from our service
        resReceiver = new ResponseReceiver();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(ServerResponseService.SOCKET_RES);
        registerReceiver(resReceiver, intentFilter);

     super.onStart();
    }

    private class ResponseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
         public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent resIntent) {

          res = resIntent.getStringExtra("RESPONSE_STR");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        unregisterReceiver(resReceiver);
        super.onStop();
    }

}
```

Here is the service which contains socket programming but not working for response.

**ServerResponseService.JAVA**

```
package com.ctpl.baatein.service;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class ServerResponseService extends Service {

    Socket socket = null;
    DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
    String reqDataStr="";
    String reqDone="";
    String res = "";
    public static final String SOCKET_RES = "response";
    String response = "";
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    public ServerResponseService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        reqDataStr = intent.getStringExtra("REQ_STRING");
        sendServerRequest();
        serverResponseService();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void  connectServer() {
        if(socket == null || !socket.isConnected()) {
            try {
                socket = new Socket("192.168.1.51", 5217);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(dataInputStream == null) {
            try {
                dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(dataOutputStream == null) {
            try {
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void serverResponseService() {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    connectServer();
                    while(res.equals("")) {
                        try {
                            //Reading String message from InputStream.
                            int strLength=dataInputStream.readInt();
                            byte[] data=new byte[strLength];
                            dataInputStream.readFully(data);
                            res = new String(data,"UTF-8");

                            if(res!=null && !res.equals("")) {
                                response = res;
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction(SOCKET_RES);
                                intent.putExtra("RESPONSE_STR", res);
                                sendBroadcast(intent);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } 
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void sendServerRequest() {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while(reqDone.equals("")) {
                        try {
                            connectServer();
                            dataOutputStream.writeUTF("individualPortName");
                            dataOutputStream.writeUTF(reqDataStr);
                            reqDone = "Done";
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            reqDone = e.getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                } 
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public String getResponse() {                    //get response
        return response;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {

        public ServerResponseService getService() {
          return ServerResponseService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what is not working? What error are you getting?

Comment: @pyerwin I can send socket request but I cannot grab response from server which send by server and return that response using broadcast receiver.